# mysql event that subtracts the current date from a specific date entered however i am working with a criteria of 4 months

Tags: mysql, events

Im tryin to develop a mysql event that subtracts the current date from a specific date entered however i am working with a criteria of 4 months, if the result of the subtraction is greater than 4 months then update a table with value '1'. So it would Be Current_date- payment_date, and if this is greater than 4 months then update flag to be '1' else '0' I want it to run daily.Please I am stuck could you help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE someTable SET someValue = (
    CASE WHEN DATE_ADD( payment_date, INTERVAL 4 MONTH ) < NOW()
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
);
```

When payment_date plus 4 months is less than the current date, the value is set to 1, otherwise 0.

Comment: Thanks You alot Ryan P Can this be implemented as an Event?

Comment: Could you please have a look at this question i am really in need of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088948/mysql-event-running-yearly-calculations