# mysql Event running yearly calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, events

I have the following code

```
CREATE EVENT myevent2
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' YEAR
STARTS commit_date + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO
UPDATE lms.loan 



        if new.app_loan_type='Computer Loan' then 
    SET NEW.app_yearly_intrst = (NEW.app_ln_amnt *(NEW.computer_interest/100));
    end if;


    if new.app_loan_type="Miscellaneous Loan" then 
    SET NEW.app_yearly_intrst = (NEW.app_ln_amnt *(NEW.miscellaneous_interest/100));
    end if;

    if new.app_loan_type="Motor Vehicle Loan" then 
    SET NEW.app_yearly_intrst = (NEW.app_ln_amnt *(NEW.motor_vehicle_interest/100));
    end if;

    if new.app_loan_type="Motor Vehicle Insurance Loan" then 
    SET NEW.app_yearly_intrst = (NEW.app_ln_amnt *(NEW.mv_insurance_interest/100));
    end if;

    if new.app_loan_type="Motor Vehicle Repair Loan" then 
    SET NEW.app_yearly_intrst = (NEW.app_ln_amnt *(NEW.mv_repair_interest/100));
    end if;


    if new.app_loan_type="Salary Advance Loan" then 
    SET NEW.app_yearly_intrst = (NEW.app_ln_amnt *(NEW.salary_advance_interest/100));
    end if;


    if new.app_loan_type="Tertiary Loan" then 
    SET NEW.app_yearly_intrst = (NEW.app_ln_amnt *(NEW.tertiary_interest/100));
    end if;

    SET NEW.app_mnthly_intrest = (NEW.app_yearly_intrst/12);
    SET NEW.app_quarterly_intrest = (NEW.app_mnthly_intrest * 3);
    SET NEW.app_amnt_owed = (NEW.app_ln_amnt+ NEW.app_yearly_intrst);

  END$$
```

I am trying to create an event to calculate interest for two loan types: 'Computer Loan' and 'Miscellaneous Loan'.. etc, on a Yearly basis, however the yearly basis is dependent on the the commit_date column that would be a year from the commit_date column, then if the app_loan_type is 'Computer Loan'or 'miscellaneous Loan' then the yearly interest is calculated Im also calculating monthly interest, Quarterly Interest and total amount owed, but my main problem is how to set the interval of commit_date and current date to be 1 year

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if you can use a column value in the `STARTS` clause, but there is a workaround for this you can schedule this event for daily and have a extra check in **all** the `IF` clause you have, to check the date difference between `commit_date` and `current_date()` is one year.

something like:

```
if new.app_loan_type="Salary Advance Loan" and DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), commit_date)), "%Y")+0 = 1 then
```

Comment: so you are saying the answer from @jeffery_the_wind above your will not work?

Comment: Im getting the following error in the answer by @jeffery_the_wind , im trying to find the error but its giving me a warm time, please if I could ask for some help again #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if datediff(date(now()),commit_date) >= 365 then if new.app_loan_type="' at line 7

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can use a dynamic value for the `timestamp` used in the create event syntax.  Instead run your event everyday, and you can use the `datediff` function in the where clause of the update query in the event to check which data should be updated.  You could also check the exact date like this: `where day(now()) = day(commit_date) and month(now()) = month(commit_date) and year(now()) = year(commit_date) + 1;`, but you wouldn't update in the case of leap eyar, so you should use something like this:

```
delimiter ||

CREATE EVENT myevent2
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS now()
DO
    UPDATE lms.loan SET app_yearly_intrst = (app_ln_amnt *(computer_interest/100)) where app_loan_type = 'Computer Loan' and datediff(date(now()),commit_date) >= 365;
    UPDATE lms.loan SET app_yearly_intrst = (app_ln_amnt *(miscellaneous_interest/100)) where app_loan_type = 'Miscellaneous Loan' and datediff(date(now()),commit_date) >= 365;
    UPDATE lms.loan SET app_yearly_intrst = (app_ln_amnt *(motor_vehicle_interest/100)) where app_loan_type = 'Motor Vehicle Loan' and datediff(date(now()),commit_date) >= 365;
    UPDATE lms.loan SET app_yearly_intrst = (app_ln_amnt *(mv_insurance_interest/100)) where app_loan_type = 'Motor Vehicle Insurance Loan' and datediff(date(now()),commit_date) >= 365;
    UPDATE lms.loan SET app_yearly_intrst = (app_ln_amnt *(mv_repair_interest/100)) where app_loan_type = 'Motor Vehicle Repair Loan' and datediff(date(now()),commit_date) >= 365;
    UPDATE lms.loan SET app_yearly_intrst = (app_ln_amnt *(salary_advance_interest/100)) where app_loan_type = 'Salary Advance Loan' and datediff(date(now()),commit_date) >= 365;
    UPDATE lms.loan SET app_yearly_intrst = (app_ln_amnt *(tertiary_interest/100)) where app_loan_type = 'Tertiary Loan' and datediff(date(now()),commit_date) >= 365;
    UPDATE lms.loan SET app_mnthly_intrest = (app_yearly_intrst/12), app_quarterly_intrest = (NEW.app_mnthly_intrest * 3), app_amnt_owed = (app_ln_amnt+ app_yearly_intrst) where datediff(date(now()),commit_date) >= 365;
END||
```

Comment: Im getting the following error, im trying to find the error but its giving me a warm time, please if I could ask for some help again
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if datediff(date(now()),commit_date) >= 365 then

        if new.app_loan_type="' at line 7

Comment: @dames - Sorry The update needs to be inside the if statement, check my answer again.

Comment: @dames -  again, i realized that the if ... then are not necessary and you should just add the criteria in the `WHERE` clause of the update syntax.  Please see the new create event syntax above and let me know if it works.

Comment: at first i was getting an error so i had to remove the delimiter $$ and End$$...and now i am getting the following eror:SQL query:

UPDATE lms.loan SET app_yearly_intrst = ( app_ln_amnt * ( miscellaneous_interest /100 ) ) WHERE app_loan_type = 'Miscellaneous Loan' AND datadiff(
date( now( ) ) ,
commit_date
) >=365;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1305 - FUNCTION lms.datadiff does not exist

Comment: @dames -- oops, that should be datediff, not datadiff, I will change it above

Comment: Im sorry to be bothering you this much but i am getting this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE lms.loan SET app_yearly_intrst = (app_ln_amnt *(miscellaneous_interest/10' at line 6